# How to avoid overlapping label's on the Bar in google bar charts?

Tags: google-visualization, bar-chart

I'm creating a stacked bar graph and need to show the label inside the stack. But Few of the label's are getting overlapped. for reference [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGKG9.jpg)

Can you please help me how to avoid overlapping using google charts ?

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStacked);

function drawStacked() {
      var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Time Period','XYZ',{ role: 'annotation'},'ABC',{ role: 'annotation'},{ role: 'annotation'},'Average'],
        ['Aug', 3754,'3754', 2089,'2089','5,843',4000],
        ['Sept', 900,'900', 200,'200', '100',4000],
  ['Oct', 2000,'2000', 4900,'4900', '6000',4000],
  ['Nov', 1700,'1700', 2200,'2200', '3900',4000],
  ['Dec', 2400,'2400', 2089,'2200', '4600',4000]
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Overview of the Tickets',
        isStacked: true,
  orientation: 'horizontal',
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Time Period',
          annotations: {}
           },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Number of Tickets'
        },
  seriesType: 'bars',
      series: {2: {type: 'line'}}
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</head>

</html>
```

Regards,
Srikanth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first, it appears you have an extra `annotation` column in your data,
that doesn't appear to belong to a specific column

copied from question above...

```
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  [
    'Time Period',
    'XYZ',
    {role: 'annotation'},
    'ABC',
    {role: 'annotation'},
    {role: 'annotation'},  // <-- extra annotation?
    'Average'
  ],
  [
    'Aug',
    3754,
    '3754',
    2089,
    '2089',
    '5,843',  // <-- extra annotation?
    4000
  ],
  ...
]);
```

this could be part of the reason it's so cluttered

regardless, use the `annotations` [configuration option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart#configuration-options) for adjustments

the config option can be used for the entire chart, or just for a specific series

```
var options = {
  // entire chart
  annotations: {
    textStyle: {
      fontSize: 10
    }
  },
  series: {
    0: {
      // series 0
      annotations: {
        stem: {
          length: 0
        },
      },
    },
    1: {
      // series 1
      annotations: {
        stem: {
          length: 16
        }
      },
    },
  }
  ...
};
```

specifically, you can use a combination of `annotations.textStyle.fontSize` and `annotations.stem.length` to prevent overlapping

see following working snippet...

`annotations.textStyle.fontSize` is reduced for the entire chart
this allows the first annotation on the second column to fit within the bar

`annotations.stem.length` is set to zero (`0`) on the first series,
and `16` on the second...

(the extra annotation from the question has been removed)

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawStacked,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawStacked() {
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Time Period', 'XYZ', {role: 'annotation'}, 'ABC', {role: 'annotation'}, 'Average'],
    ['Aug', 3754, '3754', 2089, '2089', 4000],
    ['Sept', 900, '900', 200, '200', 4000],
    ['Oct', 2000, '2000', 4900, '4900', 4000],
    ['Nov', 1700, '1700', 2200, '2200', 4000],
    ['Dec', 2400, '2400', 2089, '2200', 4000]
  ]);

  var options = {
    annotations: {
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 10
      }
    },
    series: {
      0: {
        annotations: {
          stem: {
            length: 0
          },
        },
      },
      1: {
        annotations: {
          stem: {
            length: 16
          }
        },
      },
      2: {
        type: 'line'
      }
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time Period'
    },
    isStacked: true,
    seriesType: 'bars',
    title: 'Overview of the Tickets',
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Number of Tickets'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**EDIT**

since the third annotation is needed as the total of the other two stacks,
recommend adding the series value for the total, in addition to the annotation column

and setting the total series type to `'line'`
this will place the total annotation above the rest, for sure
*so long as* there is enough room on the chart to display the annotation above the bars

to ensure enough room above bars, find the max vAxis value, and add a value that will create enough room for the annotation
then set that value as `vAxis.viewWindow.max`

you can turn off the line and point, and hide the total series from the legend if needed

in my experience, it takes quite a bit of manipulation to get a complex google chart to display nicely

see the following working snippet, which incorporates the third, 'total', annotation...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawStacked,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawStacked() {
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Time Period', 'XYZ', {role: 'annotation'}, 'ABC', {role: 'annotation'}, 'TOTAL', {role: 'annotation'}, 'Average'],
    ['Aug', 3754, '3,754', 2089, '2,089', 5843, '5,843', 4000],
    ['Sept', 900, '900', 200, '200', 1100, '1,100',  4000],
    ['Oct', 2000, '2,000', 4900, '4,900', 6900, '6,900',  4000],
    ['Nov', 1700, '1,700', 2200, '2,200', 3900, '3,900',  4000],
    ['Dec', 2400, '2,400', 2089, '2,089', 4489, '4,489',  4000]
  ]);

  // find max for all columns to set top vAxis number
  var maxVaxis = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    if (data.getColumnType(i) === 'number') {
      maxVaxis = Math.max(maxVaxis, data.getColumnRange(i).max);
    }
  }

  var options = {
    annotations: {
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 10
      }
    },
    series: {
      0: {
        annotations: {
          stem: {
            length: 0
          },
        }
      },
      1: {
        annotations: {
          stem: {
            length: 2
          }
        }
      },
      2: {
        annotations: {
          stem: {
            color: 'transparent',
            length: 16
          }
        },
        color: 'black',
        lineWidth: 0,
        pointShape: 'square',
        pointSize: 0,
        type: 'line',
        visibleInLegend: false
      },
      3: {
        type: 'line'
      }
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time Period'
    },
    isStacked: true,
    seriesType: 'bars',
    title: 'Overview of the Tickets',
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Number of Tickets',
      viewWindow: {
        max: maxVaxis + 2000
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you @WhiteHat for the reply. I need the extra annotation to display the sum of first and second stack values on top of the Bar.(First two label should display inside the stack and the sum value should display on top of the bar)  Can you please help me on this ?

Comment: Thanks alot @WhiteHat

Answer (score 3):

I think it happens because there's not enough vertical space for the labels.

Try this:

1. Save the highest value of the graph (let's call it maxNumber)
2. In the "options" set vAxis maxValue to be maxNumber plus a little more.

I have 4 horizontal lines in my graph so I wrote:

```
var options = {
                title: chartTitle,
                ....... //Your options
                vAxis: {
                    //Add more space in order to make sure the annotations are not overlapping
                    maxValue: maxNumber + maxNumber/4,
                },
```