# I am creating a stacked Line chart and need to show the label inside the stack. But Few of the label's are getting overlapped

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a stacked Line chart and need to show the label inside the stack. But Few of the label's are getting overlapped. 
Can any one Help me to resolve overlapping.
I have visited [How to avoid overlapping label's on the Bar in google bar charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771018/how-to-avoid-overlapping-labels-on-the-bar-in-google-bar-charts) but that is not working for my code.

```
<html>
<body>
<!--- Chart Data --->
<div style="width: 100%; float: left;text-align:center; margin-top:15px; background:#ffbc49 !important; color:#4e5257 !important; font-size:25px; font-weight: 800; margin-bottom:0px;  line-height:70px;">sdjskdj</div>
<div class="add_more_chart240 chart_list" id="add_more_chart240" style="margin: 10px 10px; width:calc(100% - 20px); float: left; border: 1px solid #757575;">
 <div class="forlegend col-md-12" style="display:none">
 <input type="text" class="form-control lenendname"  placeholder="Legend Name" value="sdsjdsk">
  <input type="text" class="form-control lenendname"  placeholder="Legend Name" value="L2">
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control y_series_col" min="2" max="4" placeholder="2" value="2" id="y_series_col" />
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control x_series_col" min="2" max="10" placeholder="2" value="5" id="x_series_col" /> 
   <!--Graph start-->
   <div id="curve_chart240" class="curve_chart" style="width:95%; height: 430px; margin:0 auto;"></div>
   </div>
   <!--Graph end-->
   <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">  </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
         $.each($('.chart_list'), function() {
          var class_name =  this.id ;
          var y_col = 2;
          var x_col = 5;
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          var legend_label = [];
          $("#"+class_name).find('.forlegend :input').each(function(e){ 
           legend_label.push(this.value);
          });
          data.addColumn('number', '');
          for(var i = 1;i<=y_col;i++)
          {
           data.addColumn('number', legend_label[i-1]);
           data.addColumn({type:'number', role:'annotation'});
          }
          data.addRows([[1,50.1,50.1,83.4,83.4],[2,49.3,49.3,50,50],[3,80,80,90,90],[4,17.5,17.5,23.3,23.3],[5,91,91,13.3,13.3]]);
          var options = {
           isStacked: true,
           annotations: {
             textStyle: {
            fontSize: 15
             },
             stem: {
             length: 16
             },
           },
           title: 'sdjskdjk',
           //displayAnnotations: true,
           legend: { position: 'bottom', alignment: 'middle' },
                    pointSize: 5,
           vAxis: {
            title:"% score",
            viewWindow: {
              max:100,
              min:0
            }  
           },
            hAxis : { 
            textStyle : {
             fontSize: 20 // or the number you want
            }
           },
           colors:['#52B183','#53D2F8','#B573AF','#D7E542'],
            };
          var dynamic_id = class_name.replace('add_more_chart','');
          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'+dynamic_id));
          chart.draw(data, options);
          
        });
        }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Then only show labels when hovering over one of the lines.... no source code = nothing to work with so the best you will get is suggestions like this.

Comment: Sunil, do you really think the requirement that your question contains code is in place to force you to display the body of your question as code? It's there because we need to see the code in order to help. Showing an image is pretty much like sending a picture to the doctor and asking for a consult. Without a [mcve], your question is highly unlikely to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Show them as tooltips.

```html
<html>
<body>
<!--- Chart Data --->
<div style="width: 100%; float: left;text-align:center; margin-top:15px; background:#ffbc49 !important; color:#4e5257 !important; font-size:25px; font-weight: 800; margin-bottom:0px;  line-height:70px;">sdjskdj</div>
<div class="add_more_chart240 chart_list" id="add_more_chart240" style="margin: 10px 10px; width:calc(100% - 20px); float: left; border: 1px solid #757575;">
 <div class="forlegend col-md-12" style="display:none">
 <input type="text" class="form-control lenendname"  placeholder="Legend Name" value="sdsjdsk">
  <input type="text" class="form-control lenendname"  placeholder="Legend Name" value="L2">
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control y_series_col" min="2" max="4" placeholder="2" value="2" id="y_series_col" />
  <input type="hidden" class="form-control x_series_col" min="2" max="10" placeholder="2" value="5" id="x_series_col" /> 
   <!--Graph start-->
   <div id="curve_chart240" class="curve_chart" style="width:95%; height: 430px; margin:0 auto;"></div>
   </div>
   <!--Graph end-->
   <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">  </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
         $.each($('.chart_list'), function() {
          var class_name =  this.id ;
          var y_col = 2;
          var x_col = 5;
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          var legend_label = [];
          $("#"+class_name).find('.forlegend :input').each(function(e){ 
           legend_label.push(this.value);
          });
          data.addColumn('number', '');
          for(var i = 1;i<=y_col;i++)
          {
           data.addColumn('number', legend_label[i-1]);
           data.addColumn({type:'number', role:'tooltip'});
          }
          data.addRows([[1,50.1,50.1,83.4,83.4],[2,49.3,49.3,50,50],[3,80,80,90,90],[4,17.5,17.5,23.3,23.3],[5,91,91,13.3,13.3]]);
          var options = {
           isStacked: true,
           annotations: {
             textStyle: {
            fontSize: 15
             },
             stem: {
             length: 16
             },
           },
           title: 'sdjskdjk',
           //displayAnnotations: true,
           legend: { position: 'bottom', alignment: 'middle' },
                    pointSize: 5,
           vAxis: {
            title:"% score",
            viewWindow: {
              max:100,
              min:0
            }  
           },
            hAxis : { 
            textStyle : {
             fontSize: 20 // or the number you want
            }
           },
           colors:['#52B183','#53D2F8','#B573AF','#D7E542'],
            };
          var dynamic_id = class_name.replace('add_more_chart','');
          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'+dynamic_id));
          chart.draw(data, options);
          
        });
        }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but we have to show it as label.