# How to avoid overlapping annotations in google bar charts?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I want to generate a bar chart with 2 annotations. Here is my code:

```
data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'State');
data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});
data.addColumn('number');
data.addRow(['Current State Run', '', 158468874]);
future_state_percent = [];
data.addRow(['Dynamic Container', '', 14121408]);
future_state_percent['Dynamic Container'] = (14121408 / 28481712) * 100;
data.addRow(['Public Cloud', '', 14360304]);
future_state_percent['Public Cloud'] = (14360304 / 28481712) * 100;

view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1,
                { calc: function(dt, row) {
                      return get_percent(dt, row);
                },
                type: "string",
                role: "annotation" },
                2, 
                { calc: "stringify",
                  sourceColumn: 2,
                  type: "string",
                  role: "annotation" },
               ]);

function get_percent(dataTable, row) {
    if (row == 0) {
        return ''
    }
    else {
        return future_state_percent[data.getValue(row, 0)].toFixed(2) + '%';
    }
}
```

In works, but the annotations are not being rendered in the same order in all cases, and sometimes they are rendered on top of each other, e.g.:

[image]

How can I force them to always be displayed in the same order and prevent the effect shown in the first case?

I tried the suggestion I found here:  [How to avoid overlapping label's on the Bar in google bar charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39771018/how-to-avoid-overlapping-labels-on-the-bar-in-google-bar-charts/39771794#39771794) to set the stem length, but that has no effect.

Here is a fiddle showing my code running:

https://jsfiddle.net/3t8ps1h5/1/

Could it be that the stem setting doesn't work because I am using a view? Is there a way to set the annotation to use HTML and then I could have a single annotation with a `<br/>` ?