# Google Charts Bar Chart avoid overlappin annotations

Tags: annotations, google-visualization, overlapping

Is it possible to avoid the annotations overlapping on a stacked bar chart?
The values are dynamic so there's no way, beforehand, of knowing the number of bars and the values on it that will exist on the chart.

[image]

Comment: you can adjust the stem length of each annotation, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39771794/5090771)