# Stack Chart not showing relative data on each individual stack

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Hello Everyone I am facing a issue on google charts Stack bar chart Where I am not able to get relevant data on stacks .Instead I get data of the previous stack on the next stack. I am new to charts and I know I am missing something basic but I can't resolve it
My Code is :

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
 <script>
    
    
    
            google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart', 'bar','gauge','table'] });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(loadChartsAfterFilters);    
    bindVBarChart = function (filter) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "ManagementDashboard.aspx/GetVBarChartData",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ filter: filter || null }),
                        success: function (response) {
                            var data = response.d;
                            if (data.length > 0) {
                                // Define the chart to be drawn.
                                let rows = [];
                                for (let i in data) {
                                    rows.push([data[i]["Scheme"], data[i]["Total Enrolled"], data[i]["Certified"], data[i]["Total Placed"]]);
                                }
                                var datatable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                                datatable.addColumn('string', 'Scheme');
                                datatable.addColumn('number', ' Enrolled');
                                datatable.addColumn('number', 'Certified');
                                datatable.addColumn('number', ' Placed');
                                datatable.addRows(rows);
                                var view = new google.visualization.DataView(datatable);
                                view.setColumns([0, 1, {
                                    calc: "stringify",
                                    sourceColumn: 1,
                                    type: "string",
                                    role: "annotation"
                                }, 2, {
                                        calc: "stringify",
                                        sourceColumn: 2,
                                        type: "string",
                                        role: "annotation"
                                    }, 3, {
                                        calc: "stringify",
                                        sourceColumn: 3,
                                        type: "string",
                                        role: "annotation"
                                    }
                                ]);
                                var options = {
                                    title: '',
                                    vAxis: {
                                        title: 'Scheme'
                                    },
                                    legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 1 },
                                    isStacked: true,
                                    animation: {
                                        "startup": true,
                                        duration: 1000,
                                        easing: 'out',
                                    },
                                };
                                var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(
                                    document.getElementById('vbarChart'));
                                function selectHandler() {
                                    let selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
                                    if (selectedItem) {
                                        let name = datatable.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
                                        //  let value = datatable.getValue(selectedItem.row, 1);
                                        loadReportData({
                                            DisplayName: 'Name', ColumnName: 'Name',
                                            Value: "'" + name + "'"
                                        }, "Barchart");
                                    }
                                }
                                google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
                                chart.draw(view, options);
                            }
                        },
                        failure: function (error) {
                            console.log("HBarchart Details failure-response", error);
                            swal({ title: "Barchart Error!", text: error.responseJSON.Message, icon: "warning" });
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            console.log("HBarchart Details error-response", error);
                            swal({ title: "Barchart Error!", text: error.responseJSON.Message, icon: "warning" });
                        }
                    });
                }
```

The Picture of the chart is something like this

[image]

The data I receive from Ajax is

```
0: {Scheme: "DPC", Total Enrolled: 44199, Certified: 22845, Total Placed: 14233, Place%: 32}
1: {Scheme: "NULM", Total Enrolled: 252741, Certified: 186015, Total Placed: 146590, Place%: 58}
2: {Scheme: "OTHER", Total Enrolled: 4162, Certified: 654, Total Placed: 420, Place%: 10}
3: {Scheme: "PMKUVA", Total Enrolled: 174706, Certified: 133208, Total Placed: 106258, Place%: 60}
4: {Scheme: "PMKVY", Total Enrolled: 61408, Certified: 18193, Total Placed: 3801, Place%: 6}
5: {Scheme: "TOTAL", Total Enrolled: 537216, Certified: 360915, Total Placed: 271302, Place%: 50}
```

Comment: Could you add some data that the ajax call returns as well?

Comment: I did it Sir, Please Check.

Comment: Now which Google libraries do you use?

Comment: I have mentioned everything I am using. Please tell if I am missing something

Comment: Well, I don't see the Google Visualization libraries

Comment: @yunzen -- the lib should be -- `https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js` -- @BitchLasagna -- are you referring to the fact that the annotations appear over the next bar / after the intended bar?

Comment: @WhiteHat,Yes Sir, Exactly

Comment: @yunzen, Sir, the code related to this is only this much. Please tell If I am missing something

Comment: @yunzen Yes Sir, I forgot to mention libraries in the code above now I have mentioned the library. Please Help

Comment: You are using Datatables as well. Please add that library, too.

Comment: There is no extra library I am using Sir, I can't see anything more

Comment: there's really not much you can do. the annotations will display within the bar by default, if there is enough room. so you can try reducing the annotation font size, etc. but some of the bars appear to be just too small. otherwise, it will display on top / to the right of the bar. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39771794/5090771) displays how to customize annotations for the entire chart, or a specific series...